# in highlight js the long line of code comes out of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, highlight.js

i use highlight js in my website for code
if i have a long line of code it comes out of the page and And the appearance of the page is ruined
for example:
this is a broken page of my site: https://farslearn.com/post/%D8%A2%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%B4-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D9%85%D8%AD%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA-html-%D9%88-css

this is a without problem page:
https://farslearn.com/post/free-download-package

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878) (Short answer: No.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i add this code after highlight js code and my problem is solved

```
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* Since CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```